# A smarter way to display responsive menu

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to build a menu for the header for a website. I am trying to code in the cleanest possible way and do some switches with the media queries.

I have created a demo: [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/raj56h3o/)

I will explain what it is I am trying to do and offering it out to you guys for a smart solution?

I have three steps. mobile, tablet and desktop, the menu will vary on two different pages but only slightly but I will explain so it is clear.

The menu is made up of 3 parts, so nav on the left, logo in the middle and a button on the right. Page 1 will have all three but page 2 will have no logo in the middle.

The problem I am having is that what I designed requires the nav to switch fro the left (mobile/tablet view) to the right (desktop) and the logo to switch from the middle (mobile/tablet) to the left (desktop) all within the media queries and css?

Do you guys have any thoughts or suggestions on the best way to approach this as I am currently a bit stumped?

A demo would be fantastic?

Here is my code too:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="header_row">

        <div class="header_col1">

            <nav>nav</nav>

         </div>

        <div class="header_col2">

            <div class="logo_hub">logo</div>

        </div>

        <div class="header_col3">

            <div class="login">login</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ideally the nav would stay in the same place across all screen sizes. If you have a user that is used to viewing your website through a desktop browser and the nav is located on the right, they might be confused when it is on the left on their mobile browser...

Comment: I agree, but the OP wants what the OP wants... *shrugs*

Comment: Before I write my answer - is this what you're looking for? http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/AFsak. If you're clever enough with the floats and your media queries, you should be able to tackle this without absolutely positioning anything - since that can become a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to happen with the login part on desktop?

Anyway, here's what I came up with:

CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{ /* you can omit these styles, they're just here so you can see the divs in my example! */
    background: #EEE;
    border: solid 1px #FFF;    
}

.header_row{
    position: relative;    /* if you position the parent element relative, then all child elements positioned absolute will be absolutely positioned *relative* to the parent element!  Magic! */
}
.header_col1{
    float: left;
}
.header_col2{
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0 auto;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

.header_col3{
     float: right;   
}

/* I use < 1024px for tablet view, personally... */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .header_col1{
        float: right;
    }

    .header_col2{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    .header_col3{
        display: none; /* you never mentioned what happens with this now...*/
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKendle/udjn5kzL/2/

Comment: Ok well that is certainly an interesting method. Could you explain to me about the box-sizing and what that is doing here?

Comment: Ok, it's kinda hard to explain in a comment.  Basically, it causes the browser to not *add* padding and borders onto the outside of a  div, but rather, kind of subtracts from the set width and pushes those things *inward*.  Helps a TON with percentage based layouts!  Takes away all the guess work and math.   Read this:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Yeah, TLDR, one of the benefits of using `box-sizing: border-box;` is that your actual padding will be included in the desired `width` and `height` rather than expanding it after they're set.

Comment: Thanks, that sums it up nicely.

Comment: Thanks guys that has saved me a heck of a lot of time!

Comment: NP!  Once you go border-box, you never go back.

Comment: If you wanted to vote my answer up at some point once you get that ability (enough rep. points), I'd much appreciate it!  ^_-